# Calling WCF from web Exception

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis, web-config

I'm new to creating web services and I had some errors after creating a web service using WCF and deployed it to IIS when I tried to test it using a web browser it returns me this error that I don't get:

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.CreateWsdlBindingAndPort(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, Port& wsdlPort, Boolean& newBinding, Boolean& bindingNameWasUniquified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.WsdlExporter.ExportEndpoints(IEnumerable`1 endpoints, XmlQualifiedName wsdlServiceQName, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior.MetadataExtensionInitializer.GenerateMetadata()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.EnsureInitialized()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.InitializationData.InitializeFrom(ServiceMetadataExtension extension)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.GetInitData()
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.TryHandleDocumentationRequest(Message httpGetRequest, String[] queries, Message& replyMessage)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataExtension.HttpGetImpl.ProcessHttpRequest(Message httpGetRequest)
   at SyncInvokeGet(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

the web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString=... />

  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
    <add key="wcf:serviceHostingEnvironment:useClassicReadEntityBodyMode" value="true" />
  </appSettings>


  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4000480" executionTimeout="600" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
  </system.web>




  <system.webServer>



    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />

  
   
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

  </system.webServer>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>      

      <service name="CLService.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="unsecure/XML" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" contract="CLService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestXMLEndpointBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="unsecure" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" contract="CLService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestJSONEndpointBehavior" />

        <endpoint address="xml2" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" contract="CLService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestXMLEndpointBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding" contract="CLService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="RestJSONEndpointBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
      
  

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>

        <behavior name="RestJSONEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
          <!--  <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" -->

        </behavior>
        <behavior name="RestXMLEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="600" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="200" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="600" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>


    <bindings>

      <webHttpBinding>
        
        <binding name="webHttpsBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" transferMode="Buffered" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="250000000" maxStringContentLength="250000000" maxArrayLength="250000000" maxBytesPerRead="250000000" maxNameTableCharCount="250000000" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>

        <binding name="webHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="9990000" maxBufferSize="2000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="2000000000" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transferMode="Buffered">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>

      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap" />

        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>


    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

my Service Contract methods inside IService1:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Mthod1", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Response Mthod1(String Query);



    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Mthod2",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    Response Mthod2(String Query);
```

I tried changing behaviors and bindings with no luck

the web service is deployed on IIS using https.

any idea what could be the problem?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCF Service exception error when try to host in ASP.NET Web Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307750/wcf-service-exception-error-when-try-to-host-in-asp-net-web-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the CLService.IService1 contract is exposed on multiple endpoints, the client application must refer to the endpoint name when creating a proxy instance for the contract. If the endpoint name is not confirmed, WCF will throw an error because it cannot know which endpoint to use.

If you use a browser to open the .svc file directly, the server will report an error because it does not know which endpoint you want to use. You need to add the endpoint address you want to access after the .svc file.

After my testing, this error will not affect the normal access of the program. This is just an error that the server does not know which endpoint you will use. You need to tell the service which endpoint you need to access.